# Generating Image from two vector files in sequence using Python

Tags: python, polygon, mapping

I have two folders in my system containing multiple vector files in it, i have named them as A1,A2, A3........., B1,B2,B3..... and so on. I want to map the A1 file of first folder with the A1 file of second folder but both files should have different symbology and then to export them as a image in full extent.

I have tried writing a Python code for that but it is giving the last file only as output.

In first folder it has file which contain overlay vector file in a grid and in second folder it has file which contains within vector file of the grid
My code is this:

```
> import os
import processing
> 
> for withinfiles in os.listdir (directory):
>     if withinfiles.endswith('.shp'):
>         inputwithinfile = directory + "/" + withinfiles
>         #splitting the filename for naming folders
>         inputwithinfilename, file_extention = os.path.splitext(withinfiles)

    for overlayfiles in os.listdir (directory):
        if overlayfiles.endswith('.shp'):
            inputoverlayfile = directory + "/" + overlayfiles
            #splitting the filename for naming folders
            inputoverlayfilename, file_extention = os.path.splitext(overlayfiles)

            if inputwithinfilename == inputoverlayfilename:
                withinlayer = QgsVectorLayer(inputwithinfile, "Within layer", "ogr")
                QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(withinlayer)
                withinlayer.loadNamedStyle(qml file directory)
                
                overlaylayer = QgsVectorLayer(inputoverlayfile, "overlay layer", "ogr")
                QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(overlaylayer)
                overlaylayer.loadNamedStyle(qml file directory)
                
                vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
                settings = QgsMapSettings()
                settings.setLayers([withinlayer , overlaylayer])
                settings.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
                settings.setOutputSize(QSize(800, 600))
                settings.setExtent(vlayer.extent())
                
                image_location = directory  + "/" + inputwithinfilename + '.png'
                render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)
                
                def finished():
                    img = render.renderedImage()
                    # save the image; e.g. img.save("/Users/myuser/render.png","png")
                    img.save(image_location, "png")
                
                render.finished.connect(finished)
                
                render.start()
            else:
                continue
```